# Terminate function call after a certain amount of time has elapsed in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python algorithm that will not terminate on its own. I'm doing some profiling on it and would like to run it with a bunch of different settings for a set amount of time, terminating it after that time has elapsed and starting the next run. How do I do this from within Python?

```
for c in configs:
  # what do I wrap this with do terminate it after a 
  # set amount of time and go to next loop iteration?
  runalgorithm(config)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/492519/2679935

Answer (score 0):

```
start = time.time()
endt = start + 30
while True:
    now = time.time()
    if now > endt:
        return
    else:
        print end - start
```

Try something like this within your for loop!

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work because `runalgorithm` runs forever; therefore the time checking code will never get called. Of course I could alter the algorithm with something like that, but I shouldn't have to change the algorithm.